# JavaFX TableView PropertyValueFactory Error

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm having simple problem in my JavaFX somehow it didn't work, The `PropertyValueFactory` unable to get my `ID` from class: This is my Controller:

```
public TableColumn ItemIDTableColumn;

ItemIDTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<ReceiptItem, String>("mItemID"));
ItemIDTableColumn.setCellFactory(stringCellFactory);
ItemTableView.setItems(ReceiptItem);

Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> stringCellFactory =
                new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
                    @Override
                    public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                        MyStringTableCell cell = new MyStringTableCell();
                        cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new MyEventHandler());
                        return cell;
                    }
                };

class MyStringTableCell extends TableCell<ReceiptItem, String> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(empty ? null : getString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
```

And this is my Class:

```
package ModelData;

public class ReceiptItem {
    private String mItemID;

    public String getmItemID() {
        return mItemID;
    }

    public void setmItemID(String mItemID) {
        this.mItemID = mItemID;
    }
}
```

As seen here, I'm using getter and setter, so anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

`PropertyValueFactory` expects the first letter of the property name in the getter method to be upper case. In this case it looks for a method named `getMItemID`. Your method is called `getmItemID` however...

Note that updates to a `ReceiptItem` will not automatically update the `TableView`, since you do not provide a `mItemIDProperty` method returning a property object wrapping the property value.

Answer (score 0):

My Controller Class name is **ControllerPreviewInvoice.java** , and I was getting data for my table columns from the class **FinalProduct**...which was defined in the controller class

Later I found out that **FinalProduct** class should be public and defined separately like **FinalProduct.java**... I was using IntelliJ IDEA IDE, so it suggested me to do it, and it worked... It started loading all the data in columns now.

Comment: I'm not sure this post was posted to the correct question. You should check that. Your comment seems completely unrelated to the topic at hand.

Answer (score -1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html):

> ```
> TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");
> firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
> ```
>
> In this example, the "firstName" string is used as a reference to an assumed firstNameProperty() method in the Person class type (which is the class type of the TableView items list).

Your usage of `PropertyValueFactory`:

```
new PropertyValueFactory<ReceiptItem, String>("mItemID")
```

will lookup for

```
ReceiptItem.mItemIDProperty()
```

Getters and setters follow a typical naming convention of `getFoo()` and `setFoo()`. Java 8 / JavaFX introduces a convention for "property getters" which follow the naming convention `fooProperty()`, and return a property that can be bound by the JavaFX view like an [`ObjectProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) or a [`StringProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/StringProperty.html).

Comment: Thanks for the respond, After I tried your method it show `Error:(116, 42) java: incompatible types: javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn,javafx.scene.control.TableCell> cannot be converted to javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<ModelData.ReceiptItem,java.lang.String>,javafx.scene.control.TableCell<ModelData.ReceiptItem,java.lang.String>>` which I tried to fix changing field to <S,T>, it provides new CallBack which accepts <S,T>, for both TableColumn and Table Cell, which is not recognized S?

Comment: Anyway, I dont think changing the `public TableColumn ItemIDTableColumn;` will solve the problem, cause when I tried in another program, It works perfectly without changing, I just don't know why in this case it wont work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. I think the only thing you need to change from your original code is changing the type of `mItemID` to `StringProperty`, and adding a method: `mItemIDProperty()` which returns it. Your getters and setters would then also need to change to use the `.get()` and `.set()` methods of `StringProperty`. From your response, it looks like you tried to incorporate the example code that I copied from the javadoc, which is only meant to demonstrate what the `PropertyValueFactory` constructor is trying to load.